# How to stop any particular service in laravel 5.2?

Tags: angularjs, service, laravel-5, php-5.6

If I want to upload 3 file into server then I just select 3 files.

then called 3 services like :

1 `something/api/uploadFile` (uplodaing first file)

2 `something/api/uploadFile` (uplodaing second file)

3 `something/api/uploadFile` (uplodaing third file)

**Now my question is how can cancel only second service (stop second file to upload into server)?**

**I am using Angular js for frontend**

**HTML Code :**

```
<button type="button" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)"  ng-model="files" ngf-model-invalid="invalidFiles" ngf-model-options="modelOptionsObj" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-pattern="pattern" ngf-accept="acceptSelect"  ngf-capture="capture" ngf-drag-over-class="dragOverClassObj" ngf-validate="validateObj" ngf-resize="resizeObj" ngf-resize-if="resizeIfFn($file, $width, $height)" ngf-dimensions="dimensionsFn($file, $width, $height)" ngf-duration="durationFn($file, $duration)" ngf-keep="keepDistinct ? 'distinct' : keep" ngf-fix-orientation="orientation" ngf-max-files="maxFiles" ngf-ignore-invalid="ignoreInvalid" ngf-run-all-validations="runAllValidations" ngf-allow-dir="allowDir" class="drop-box ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-max-size ng-valid-min-height ng-valid-min-width ng-valid-ratio ng-valid-max-ratio ng-valid-min-ratio ng-valid-max-duration ng-valid-min-duration ng-valid-duration ng-valid-validate-async-fn ng-valid-max-height ng-valid-max-width ng-valid-dimensions btn btn-save" ngf-drop-available="dropAvailable" >Upload File or Drag File</button>
```

**angular controller code:**

```
    $scope.fileUpload = true;
$scope.uploadFiles = function (files, singleRelease) {
    $scope.getFileFormat(files);
    $scope.files = files;
    $scope.fileUpload = false;
    if ($scope.releaseCheck == false || $scope.releaseCheck == undefined) {
        angular.forEach(files, function (uploadFile, index) {
            $scope.uploadSingleFile(uploadFile);
        });
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.files, function (file, index) {
        $scope.uploadFile(file);
    })
};

    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files, singleRelease) {
    $scope.getFileFormat(files);
    $scope.files = files;
    $scope.fileUpload = false;
    if ($scope.releaseCheck == false || $scope.releaseCheck == undefined) {
        angular.forEach(files, function (uploadFile, index) {
            $scope.uploadSingleFile(uploadFile);
        });
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.files, function (file, index) {
        $scope.uploadFile(file);
    })
};
```

**LARAVEL Controller function code**

```
    public function uploadDirectFile(Request $request) {
    $uni_msg = \CmsMessage::getUniMessage();
    $postData = $request->all();
    $mediaName = 'file_' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $fileData = [];
    $destinationPath = \CmsHelper::createFolderIfNotExists('directFileUploads/');
        if (null !== $postData['file'] && $postData['file']->getFilename() != '') {
            $uploadeImage = \CmsHelper::handleMedia($postData['file'], $destinationPath, $mediaName);
            $fileData['original_name'] = $postData['file']->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileData['mediaName'] = $uploadeImage['mediaName'];
            $fileData['mediaType'] = $uploadeImage['mediaType'];
            $fileData['mediaMime'] = $uploadeImage['mediaMime'];
            $fileData['file_path'] = url('/') . '/directFileUploads/';
        }
    if (sizeof($fileData) > 0) {
        return Response::json(['status' => 1, 'data' => $fileData, 'fileHashKey' => $postData['fileHashKey'], 'message' => $uni_msg['success']]);
    }
    return Response::json(['status' => 0, 'message' => $uni_msg['error']]);
}
```

Thanks Ahead.

Comment: Please clarify how you upload files. What frontend framework do you use. Provide code of what you've already tried.

Comment: @ Frank Provost I have added code here.

Comment: the title of your question is misleading. Actually you want to abort the upload on client side (angular) and not on backend side (laravel). Does this maybe answer your question: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1096 ?

Comment: thanks for change my view. But upload.abort will stop all progressive upload.  And we need to stop only single file to upload.